# react testing library: can you mock <img>?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

With React, I have an overlay component that renders on top of an `<img>`, setting its width/height/left/top to that of the image using various callbacks and other shenanigans. When I render the component, `onload` doesn't fire. When I manually run `fireEvent.load(img)` via react testing library it correctly fires, but none of the properties of the image are set ( clientWidth , actualWidth, etc.). I need these because the `Overlay` doesn't render if width/height are zero. I believe these aren't set because react testing library doesn't actually computer the layout/render of the component.

I thought I would mock the `<img>` tag, but it seems you can't do that. I tried mocking `global.Image` but its constructor doesn't seem to be called by the renderer.

Is there a way to mock `<img>` or manually set `clientWidth`, `actualWidth`, etc.?

Essentially my code looks something like this:

```
...
const [imgLoaded, setImageLoaded] = useState(false);
const onLoad = ()=>setImageLoaded(true);
const [imgWidth, setImageWidth] = useState();
useEffect(()=>{
   if (!imgLoaded){
      return;
   }
   //imgRef assigned elsewhere
   setImageWidth(imgRef.actualWidth);
}, [imgLoaded]);
......
return <>
   <img onload={onLoad}/>
   <Overlay width={imgWidth}/>
```

Comment: @mandy8055 - could you elaborate? How would I mock the properties of it without mocking it?/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For mocking `<img>` tag, you can manually set the properties like `clientWidth` and `actualWidth` using the ***[`Object.defineProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)*** method to define these properties on the `imgRef` object. I would create a utility function to mock the properties. Something like:

```js
function mockImageProperties(image, properties) {
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(properties)) {
    Object.defineProperty(image, key, {
      value,
      writable: true, // You can use them as per your requirement.
      configurable: true,
    });
  }
};
```

Then in your test file:

```js
// ...Rest of the code
it('should test', () => {
  const { getByRole } = render(<YourComponent />);

  const image = getByRole('img');
  mockImageProperties(image, {
    clientWidth: 100,
    actualWidth: 100,
    // Mock other props as needed
  });

  fireEvent.load(image);

  // Your test assertions
});
```